# Which SQLCMD.exe to use (x64 or x86) -- SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, 64-bit, sqlcmd

I have SQL Server 2008 installed in a Vista x64 machine.
When I look for the sqlcmd.exe, i find 2 versions, the x64 and the x86:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe

Which one should I use ? Is there an advantage of using one over the other?

Thanks, Nestor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 64-bit version - it was built specifically for your 64-bit CPU and as such will run better.

Comment: The 64bit version also won't have the 2GB memory limitation of SSMS (which is 32bit by default) or the 32bit version of SQLcmd